# Opposite of R's deparse(substitute(var))?

Tags: r, reflection

I'm currently calling `rp.slider` from the `tkrplot` library with multiple arguments in a loop, for example:

```
rp.slider(rpplot, param1)
rp.slider(rpplot, param2)
```

etc.

Ideally, I'd like to do this within a loop, e.g.

```
for(i in 1:10) 
  rp.slider(rpplot, foo(paste(param,i,sep="")))
```

Where `foo` will encode the string to a variable name (symbol?). rp.slider converts the argument into a string using `deparse(substitute(var))`. Is there a `foo` function that will let me do this? I've tried `as.symbol`, `as.name`, and `parse` (among others) without success.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

To clarify, `deparse(substitute(x))` returns `[1] "x"` - I'd like a way of returning the same output from a string, i.e. which `foo` outputs `[1] "x"` for input `deparse(substitute(foo("x")))`? Is it possible?

Comment: To clarify, `deparse(substitute(x))` returns `[1] "x"` - I'd like a way of returning the same output from a string, i.e. which `foo` outputs `[1] "x"` for input `deparse(substitute(foo("x")))`? Is it possible?

Comment: You should try to avoid loops...

Comment: @aL3xa : when plotting, using the apply family is not feasible in most cases. apply works within a local environment, and does funny things when combined with plotting functions.

Comment: The `plyr` family of "_" functions are another viable alternative here. I also like the `failwith` option that provides a failsafe for when a particular plot doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try`eval(parse(text=...))` or `eval(substitute(...))`.

`parse(text=...)` turns the string in an expression, `eval` evaluates the expression. Be sure to use the `text` argument, as `parse` normally looks for a file. Forgetting that is a common mistake. See also `?parse` and `?eval`.

```
> a <- 10
> x <- deparse(substitute(a))
> eval(parse(text=x))
[1] 10
```

To show how to use it, your adjusted code :

```
for(i in 1:10)
  eval(parse(text=paste("rp.slider(rpplot,param",i,")",sep="")))
```

`substitute` substitutes values in a language object by the strings given in the second argument :

```
for(i in 1:10)
  eval(
    substitute(
      rp.slider(rpplot,x),
      list(x=as.name(paste("param",i,sep="")))
    )
  )
```

Or, using the example in the help files :

```
library(rpanel)
rpplot <- rp.control(title = "Demonstration of rp.tkrplot", h = 1,j=1)

redraw <- function(panel) {
  rp.tkrreplot(panel, tkrp)
}
x <- c('h','j')
rp.tkrplot(rpplot, tkrp, function(panel) plot((1:20)^panel$j, (1:20)^panel$h))

eval(parse(text=paste("rp.slider(rpplot, ",x[1]," , action = redraw,
    from = 0.05, to = 2.00, resolution = 0.05)")))

eval(
  substitute(
    rp.slider(rpplot, x, action=redraw, from=0.05, to=2.00, resolution=0.05),
    list(x = as.name(x[2]))
  )
)
```

---

The explanation why this is necessary, can be found within the source code of rp.slider. The construct to get the varname inside the function is not the standard used in R. In fact, the use of 'deparse(substitute())' is strongly discouraged, exactly for this reason. With most functions, `as.expression("x")` works to get the variable in using a variable name. Alas, the author of the `rpanel` package made this impossible.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid - comes back with `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function`. Thanks though.

Comment: @daveslanted : It works perfectly well, as shown by the above code. If you don't manage to get it running, it's because there's something else wrong. Take into account that you only need `parse(text=...)` to get an expression for use within a function, as explained above.

Comment: I tried, `rp.slider(rpplot, eval(parse(text=param1)))` but it gave the above error. Please see my clarification under the question - if I run `deparse(substitute(eval(parse(text="x"))))` I get `[1] "eval(parse(text = \"x\"))"`. I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even possible, as it seems that the deparse/substitute is evaluated before the inner function calls? Thanks again.

Comment: @daveslanted: also, the input of parse(text=...) is a string, meaning you need parse(text="param1").

Comment: Typo sorry, I did quote param1. Still no luck, I think because `deparse(substitute(parse(text="x")))` still returns `[1] "parse(text = \"x\")"` rather than `[1] "x"` - so I think it's failing for this reason. Getting the error as above.

Comment: @daveslanted : you run `y <- deparse(substitute(x))` and `eval(parse(text="y"))`. If you read the help files, you'd see that *everything* in the substitute function is transformed to string. You can't nest these things. Try the code I gave you and see if that works.

Comment: Your list construct in the edit would be nice, except the parameters haven't been defined - they are used as references within a callback. Please see example on: [http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/rpanel/html/rp.tkrplot.html](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/rpanel/html/rp.tkrplot.html) - the variable h in the last line is what I'd like to quote in a string for looping/`sapply`. Many thanks.

Comment: @daveslanted : I adapted the parse construct to parse the complete call. That should work. See the edited answer.

Comment: Copied your answer verbatim, it doesn't work in this instance - I think it comes back to your point about not being able to nest these things, as that's effectively what's happening on the first line of rp.slider. Think I'm going to have to reimpliment `rp.slider` to avoid the nested `deparse(substitute(var))` construct.

Comment: @ daveslanted : for me it works perfectly. I added the code I used to test it.

Comment: A cleaner way to do this is to use `substitute` or `call` - you should never have to construct a text string, then parse and evaluate it.

Comment: @hadley : then you're talking about the package I presume? I can't see how call() or substitute() can help the op, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @joris : thanks, your example works, though it's a shame that a whole string has to be parsed/evaluated rather than just the variable name. As you and Greg Snow say, it's probably better to avoid calling this function if possible and see if there's an alternative. Thanks for your detailed answer and responses to comments.

Comment: In essence: `substitute(rp.slider(rpplot, x), list(x = as.name("h")))`

Comment: @hadley : true. Thx for the tip, I added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The rp.slider function looks like it is in rpanel, not tkrplot.

A possible alternative is to use the tkexamp function in the TeachingDemos package, it constructs a tk gui for a plot (using tkrplot) based on a list, you could construct the list in your loop, then call tkexamp.  Or you can look at the code to tkexamp to see how it parses the list (in a loop) to create the tk controls, though looking through the code may scare you off from that idea.